# Passing javascript array data to php and use it to change data in an if else statement

Tags: javascript, php, view

On a site I'm working on, we have a slider that I am wanting to grab the javascript data array ( newValue ) and pass that or pull that into my PHP and add it into my if / else statement so when the number changes and does not comply with the if, it will give me a specific statement.

Here is the javascript code block I have:

```
setEventListeners() {
this.slider.noUiSlider.on('change', () => {
  let newValue = this.slider.noUiSlider.get()

  this.sliderInput.value = newValue

  if (newValue === this.sliderMax) {
    this.sliderHasHitMax()
    this.sliderQuantityInput.value = this.sliderStep
  } else if (newValue === this.sliderMin) {
    this.sliderHasHitMin()
    window.dispatchEvent(uCreateEvent('input-slider-change'))
  } else {
    this.sliderHasChanged()
    window.dispatchEvent(uCreateEvent('input-slider-change'))
  }

  if (this.stepsAsTooltip) {
    this.sliderQuantityInput.value =
      this.slider.noUiSlider.get() / this.sliderMin
    this.sliderQuantityInput.dispatchEvent(uCreateEvent('input'))
  }
})
```

The php if statement that im working with is :

```
if ( isset($data['price_share']) && $data['price_share'] > 50 && $data['unit'] == 1 ) {
    $unitShare = 'summary-payment';
} else {
    $unitShare = 'payment';
}
```

The end goal. When the slider changes, it obviously increments 1 through 10(1 being min, and 10 being max) as that number changes, I want to pull the javascript array newValue into PHP if statement and when that number is equal to 1 I want it to be true and when the value is bigger than 1 I want it to be false...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to send the new value to PHP with AJAX.

Comment: Thank you - I will have to look into that procedure.  
And to clarify, the value in the javascript is actually called - newValue